# How can i create user wise database after successfully registered in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net

i have a requirment,  like when user do successfull registration  into my application a new database will be created by his name. So its important to create a new database programmaticall.
 Can you please help me. Its MVC5 asp.net.

Comment: So many ways to do it, any specific requirement? It makes me thing why one would create a database per user however.. but that's none of my business...

Comment: Thanks @Adriani6.  Not any specific requiremen. I just need to create a database by user name after successful Registratio.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to create a new database using a Stored Procedure.

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CreateUserDB", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DBName", DBName));
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // Wrap in using()
```

conn - Connection String
DBName - Parameter passed to stored procedure (database name in this example)

Your Stored Procedure would contain the SQL code needed to create the Database.

Your SP would look like the following (or similar)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateUserDB
   @DBName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @CREATEDBSCRIPT AS NVARCHAR = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' ON(FILENAME = '''c:\myFile.mdf''') FOR ATTACH;'

END
```

Comment: Thanks,  but what SP will execute?  Scripts or bak file. I fried to restore bak file but its not working. Showing error for. Mdf and.. Ldf file. Thanks agai. I need to create database  with all staff in it like, table SP etc.

Comment: It will execute a stored procedure on the sql server, I have included a sample SP code by sample I mean it's near complete, you'll need to modify to fit your context and environment.

Comment: Database will be created with more then 60 tables and SP. So you mean all scripts write into the SP?

Comment: You don't have to, you can call the mdf file from the store procedure on the new table, see the edited Sql script it'll look similar to that.

Comment: Thanks dear, let me try and let you know.